# How to validate ngx-select-dropdown on from submit?

Tags: validation, angular7, angular-validation, ngx-select-dropdown

I have a form in which i used ngx-select-dropdown with angular7. In my form select option is required. I want to validate it on form submitting. But my validate methods are not working with ngx-select-dropdown library, and in documentation of ngx-select-dropdown i could not found any helping information about validation. Is it possible to validate it ?

```
 <ngx-select-dropdown (change)="onSelectDropdown($event)" name="unit" [config]="config"
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && !unit.valid }"
[options]="unitsList"
[(ngModel)]="createUser.unit" id="unit" #unit="ngModel" required>
</ngx-select-dropdown>
<div *ngIf="f.submitted && !unit.valid" class="invalid-feedback">Unit is required</div>
```

Comment: which version of `ngx-select-dropdown` were you using?